# Bouncer plugins in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a jquery plugin that bounces a div element periodically infinite times. I have no such example website to show, but what I want is a div element that bounces to right(say) and bounces back to left. And at the time of bounce I want to change the content. Also bounce should go on. It should not stop or slow down.

I searched in
http://jquery.com/
http://mootools.net/

but found nothing that I wanted. There is bounce that stops after sometime.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have interpret your description correctly, you want a div that moves left and right continuously and changes content on "arrival". I'm still not sure if you want to toggle content or loop through more content.

A little illustration to clarify:

```
 __________                        __________
|          |  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  |          |
| content1 |                      | content2 |
|__________|  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  |__________|

     |---------------------------------|
content change                  content change
```

Now, because the VERY specific request, I highly doubt there's such a plugin available. You just have to be creative yourself! Luckily, I'm a nice guy and save you some work.

See the [online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NUK72/).

My javascript function:

```
function startBouncing(selector, content, duration, easing) {
    // get the required movement (parent width - element width)
    var movement = $(selector).parent().width() - $(selector).width();
    var contentIndex = 0; // we want to start with content index 0

    // define function that makes element go forth
    var goForth = function() {
        // start animation and change text
        $(selector).animate({
            'margin-left': movement
        }, duration, easing, goBack).children('p:first').html(content[contentIndex % content.length]);

        contentIndex++; // increment index for next time
    };

    // define function that makes element go back
    var goBack = function() {
        // start animation and change text
        $(selector).animate({
            'margin-left': 0
        }, duration, easing, goForth).children('p:first').html(content[contentIndex % content.length]);

        contentIndex++; // increment index for next time
    };

    // start the sequence
    goForth();
}
```

Which I call using:

```
var content = [
    'content #1',
    'content #2',
    'content #3'
]; // if you wish to toggle, just use 2 elements

// calling the function
startBouncing('#bouncer', content, 2000, 'linear');
```

And finally, the HTML:

```
<div style="background-color: gray; height: 50px; width: 500px;">
    <div id="bouncer" style="background-color: #ff0000; height: 50px; width: 50px;">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It might not look good, but it works. I haven't spend a second in optimizing the code.

---

**edit**

I've edited the function so you specify a different duration and easing per side.

```
function startBouncing(selector, content, duration1, duration2, easing1, easing2) {
    // get the required movement (parent width - element width)
    var movement = $(selector).parent().width() - $(selector).width();
    var contentIndex = 0; // we want to start with content index 0

    // define function that makes element go forth
    var goForth = function() {
        // start animation and change text
        $(selector).animate({
            'margin-left': movement
        }, duration1, easing1, goBack).children('p:first').html(content[contentIndex % content.length]);

        contentIndex++; // increment index for next time
    };

    // define function that makes element go back
    var goBack = function() {
        // start animation and change text
        $(selector).animate({
            'margin-left': 0
        }, duration2, easing2, goForth).children('p:first').html(content[contentIndex % content.length]);

        contentIndex++; // increment index for next time
    };

    // start the sequence
    goForth();
}
```

For more advanced easing strings, you should use an plugin that adds more easing strings like [this](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) one.

Comment: I am not used to the fiddle. I have all the code in a html file and i also added "jquery-1.7.1.js" in that file. But the code is not working! what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably called the function before the dom is loaded. Try using calling it AFTER the dom is loaded by either putting the javascript later on in the file or run the script when the DOM is ready with loading (`$(function() { //code goes here });`).

Comment: again a question :) can we change the speed of the animation? like it looks like it is bouncing? in any direction say while it is striking, it strikes with more speed and while it goes to another end it slows down the speed :)

Comment: As you can see in the function, I've allowed you to give an `duration` and `easing` argument. The duration is the amount of time from left to right in milliseconds. You can use a string for the easing parameter. Just set that parameter to `swing` like this: `startBouncing('#bouncer', content, 2000, 'swing');`. That should work for you!

Comment: swing argument works as pendulum, it slows down in both direction(left and right), is there any other way? just to slow down in one direction(either left or right)

Answer (score 0):

use should combine the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function using an cool bouncing easing effect (requires jquery ui). i order to make it bounce repeatedly, use the setTimeout function..